# How to take current page and 'report' php

Tags: php

It's a little bit newbie question but how can I make such a button? My pages are like `index.php?id=1..` or `pcs.php?id=12..`. I want to put one button where people can 'report' if something is not right on that page.

Nothing special just when they click on 'Report' open one box where they write what is wrong and send mail to administrator.

edit: Like here we have 'flag' button..

Comment: If anyone know some tutorial. No need to give me full and work code.

Comment: I think you can apply a simple <a>.. link it report.php where there is a form where people can type the report.. what do you think?

Comment: Is one option and probably I'll use this. But I searched for something with popup where I can choose from several options why this link is reported. But I gues this must be done with javascript?

Comment: Just create a select field with the values your users can choose from inside the form.  No javascript needed

Comment: But when is with js I can do it without redirect to other page. Just will popup one window with 2-3 options and button send.

Comment: Yes, you can use javascript to generate the popup if you want.  However you can use a form to generate the report without PHP, as it will automatically redirect back to the page the user was on if no output was generated.

Comment: Do you know where I can read about this way? Some tutorial something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple PHP form, and make the button the submit button for the form.  If you know nothing about PHP forms and mailing, this page could help you.

http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

**REVISION**- Passing the current page to the form is easy.  One way to do it is to print the current page into a hidden element inside the form, which will be sent through to your forms action page along with the information that the user entered.

example-

```
<input type ='hidden'  name ='url_param' value ='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'>
```

Comment: This will help me for the actual contact form. Thank's!

Comment: @user3346678 edited for a more complete answer

Comment: When is hidden type will administrator see link of reported page?

Comment: You take the value of the hidden element in the forms action page, and print it to the report or email that you're generating

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me, what your actual question is, but I think you want to know, how you can get the URL of the current page. The global variable `$_SERVER` may help you with that:

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is the path and filename of the current script, without the query string, e. g. `index.php`.
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the full URI after the domain part, e. g. `index.php?id=1`.

Using those values, you can redirect the users to a report page, where they can add an additional message. E-mails can be send using the [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function or a third-party mailing framework like PHPMailer.